# Jpeg compression matrix after quantization

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I try to write an m-file in matlab that performs jpeg compression in an image with 256x256 dimensions, in the code below i split the image into 8x8 sub-blocks and perform dct transform and after quantization. My problem is that i want also after quantization to keep in a matrix the new generated values in order to have a 256x256 matrix with also the 0 values and then to perform the zig zag operation. My code is below:

```
clc;
clear all;
data=imread('cameraman.tif');
x=double(data);

%length of image with no compression
len=256*256;
data1=uint8(zeros(size(data)));

%quantization weigting table

   qv1= [ 16   11   10   16   24   40   51   61
          12   12   14   19   26   58   60   55
          14   13   16   24   40   57   69   56
          14   17   22   29   51   87   80   62
          18   22   37   56   68  109  103   77
          24   35   55   64   81  104  113   92
          49   64   78   87  103  121  120  101
          72   92   95   98  112  100  103   99];

      final=zeros(256,256);

      count1=0;
      for row=1:8:256
          for column = 1:8:256
          %shift down pixel
          x=double(data(row:row+7,column:column+7))-128;
          %8x8 dct transform
          xf=dct2(x);
          %quantization
          xf=round(xf./qv1).*qv1;
          final(row+7,column+7)=xf;
          count1=count1+sum(xf(:)~=0);
          %inverse dct transformation,
          data1(row:row+7,column:column+7)=idct2(xf)+128;
          end
      end
```

The "final" variable i want to make the matrix i have described above. I take error as i have it. I don't know how to change the code in order to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that instead of 
`final(row+7,column+7)` 
you should have 
`final(row:row+7,column:column+7)`, otherwise you have an assignment mismatch. 
Also, the `double` conversion within the loop seems unnecessary as you already convert to `double` before it is entered.